# Make multiple directories and put files into each one

Tags: bash

I've been attempting to mkdir multiple directories and the touch a set of files into each one.

I'm basically trying to combine the following:

```
mkdir ./file_directory{1..10};
```

then in each directory

```
touch ./file_directory{1..2} file_name{1..10};
```

When I execute touch it creates a the file_name{1..10} under ./

I've been looking around. Please forgive me for I have sinned and am new to not only bash, but coding/scripting in general. I'm attempting to create these files to learn scripting. Although this is technically my first project, I'm going to

Comment: If you want to create a file in a subdirectory, you need to connect them with `/`, e.g. `touch ./dir/filename`

Comment: Oh, wow.. I feel like a complete idiot. It's been a long day. Thank you for your quick reponse. I deserve a prompt kick to the knees.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `/` between the directory and filename to create a file in the subdirectory:

```
mkdir file_directory{1..10}
touch file_directory{1..10}/file_name{1..10}
```

Comment: nice, didn't realize touch could create an empty file like this! Good to know